# Selects dependientes 2 niveles

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Necesito la vuestra ayuda :(

Tengo un problema con los dropdown dependientes en 2 niveles, uno es para país, y el otro para ciudad.
El problema esta en que cuando clico un país, en el dropdown de la ciudad me sale pegado dentro de el toda la pagina entera html y no consigo ver donde fallo... espero que me podais ayudar...

Aquí está el codigo:

```js
// JavaScript Document
var  conexion = null;

function crearXMLHttpRequest() {
 var xmlhttp=false;
 try{
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 }catch(e){
  try{
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  catch(E){
   if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
 }
 return xmlhttp; 
}

//declaramos los dropdowns del documento HTML
var listadoSelects = new Array();
listadoSelects[0] = "pais";
listadoSelects[1] = "ciudad";

/*funcion que devuelve la posicion donde esta el elemento dentro del array*/
function buscar(array, valor){
 var i = 0;
 
 while(array[i]){
  if(array[i] == valor){
   return i;
   i++;
  }
 }
 
 return null;
}

function cargarContenido(idOrigen){
 //cojemos la posicion que ocupa el dropdown que tiene que ser puesto en el array
 var posicionDestino = buscar(listadoSelects,idOrigen)+1;  
 //obtenemos el dropdown que el usuario ha modificado
 var origen = document.getElementById(idOrigen);
 //obtenemos la opcion seleccionada
 var seleccionada = origen.options[origen.selectedIndex].value;
 
 //si el usuario eligio la opcion Elige.. no buscaremos nada en la BBDD
 if(seleccionada == ""){
  var x = posicionDestino;
  var actual = null;
  
  //deshabilitamos las opciones de el select dependiente ya que no hemos seleccionado ningun valor
  while(listadoSelects[x]){
   actual = document.getElementById(listadoSelects[x]);
   actual.length = 0;
   
   var nuevaOpcion = document.createElement("option");
   nuevaOpcion.value = 0;
   nuevaOpcion.innerHTML = "Selecciona una opción..";
   actual.appendChild(nuevaOpcion);
   actual.disabled = true;
   x++;
  }
  
 }else if(idOrigen != listadoSelects[listadoSelects.length-1]){
  var idDestino = listadoSelects[posicionDestino];
  var destino = document.getElementById(idDestino);
  
  var ajax = crearXMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("GET","action.php?action=dependientes&select="+idDestino+"&option="+seleccionada, true);
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax.readyState == 1){
     destino.length = 0;
     var nuevaOp = document.createElement("option");
     nuevaOp.value = 0;
     nuevaOp.innerHTML = "Cargando...";
     destino.appendChild(nuevaOp);
     destino.disabled = true;
     
    }if(ajax.readyState == 4){
     destino.parentNode.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    }
   
  }
  
  ajax.send(null);
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" lang="es-es">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/icSquared_v1.0.css"/>
  <title>Información del usuario</title>
 </head>
<body>
<div>
 <div class="registro">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2" style="left:79%; margin-top:2%">
    <?php echo $msgReg; ?>
    <form action="action.php?accion=userRegisterInfo" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <h3 class="text-center" style="font-size:35px"> Datos Personales </h3><br />
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Que eres?</label>
      <?php desplegable_tipoUser(-1); ?>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Apellidos</label>
      <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Introduce tus apellidos"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Fecha de nacimiento</label>
      <input type="date" name="fechaNac" required="required" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Sexo:</label><br />
      <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="male" checked="checked"/> <i class="fa fa-mars fa-lg"></i> Hombre &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="female" /> <i class="fa fa-venus fa-lg"></i> Mujer 
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Pais:</label>
      <?php desplegable_pais(); ?>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Población:</label>
      <select disabled="disabled" name="ciudad" id="ciudad">
       <option value="0">Selecciona una opción..</option>
      </select>
     </div> 
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Imagen de Perfil:</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
      <input type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="foto_perfil" required="required">
     </div>   
     <br/>
     <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="enviar" value="Guardar" style="margin-left:40%"/>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/selectsDependientes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y aquí el cacho de código php:

```
<?php
//connect BD function
function conectar(){
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxxx","xxxx");

    //set the language
    $connect->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    return $connect;
}

//disconect BD function
function desconectar($connect){
    mysqli_close($connect);
}


    //dropdown pais 
function desplegable_pais(){ 
$conexion = conectar(); $sql = "SELECT * FROM PAIS";

    echo '<select name="pais" id="pais" onChange="get_ciudad(this.value);">';
    echo '<option value="0">Elige un País</option>';
    if($resultado=$conexion->query($sql)){
        while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo '<option value="'.$fila[0].'">'.$fila[1].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<p> Error en la conexion o consulta.. </p> <br />';
    }

    echo '</select>';
    desconectar($conexion);
}




<?php 
if($action == "dependientes"){
    $listadoSelects=array(
    "pais"=>"lista_pais",
    "ciudad"=>"lista_ciudad"
    );

    $destino = $_GET['select'];
    $seleccionado = $_GET['option'];

    //funcion que valida que el select enviado por GET exista
    function validar($destino){
        global $listadoSelects;
        $validado = false;

        if(!isset($listadoSelects[$destino])){
            $validado = true;
        }

        return $validado;
    }

    //funcion que valida la opcion seleccionada
    function validarOp($seleccionado){
        $validado = false;

        if(is_numeric($seleccionado)){
            $validado = true;
        }

        return $validado;
    }

    if(validar($destino) && validarOp($seleccionado)){
        $conexion = conectar();

        $sql = "SELECT idPoblacion, nombre,comunidadAut FROM POBLACION WHERE id_pais='".$seleccionado."'";

        if($resultado = $conexion -> query($sql)){
            echo '<select name="'.$destino.'" id="'.$destino.'" onChange="cargarContenido(this.id)">';
            echo '<option value="0">Elige</option>';
            while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                //$fila[0] = htmlentities($fila[0]);

                echo "<option value='".$fila[0]."'>".$fila[1]." - ".$fila[2]."<option>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hola Anna, veo que has editado tu pregunta con la solucion. StackOverflow no funciona asi, debes dejar la pregunta original como esta (o con las ediciones necesarias que aclaren tus dudas) pero no debes editarla con la respuesta, sino postear una respuesta con la solucion para asi quedan claramente diferenciadas para futuros usuarios. He revertido la edición para que quede como estaba, ahora deberás postear una respuesta con los pasos que te han servido para solucionar el problema, al cabo de 48 horas podrás aceptarla como respuesta válida. Un saludo! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hay un fallo en la línea que muestra las ciudades:

```
         echo "<option value='".$fila[0]."'>".$fila[1]." - ".$fila[2]."<option>";
```

Nunca se cierra la etiqueta `<option>` si no que se abre una nueva, y eso es por lo que se ve todo pegado. La solución es simple, cierra la etiqueta `<option>`:

```
         echo "<option value='".$fila[0]."'>".$fila[1]." - ".$fila[2]."</option>";
```

Comment: Grácias ya he cambiado el pequeño fallo pero sigue sin irme.. ahora no hace ningun tipo de accion ._.'

Comment: Hola @Anna, por favor define "no hace ningun tipo de accion". ¿Qué es lo que no va?¿Qué error ves?¿Qué acción es la esperada?

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo mas simple  o sencillo que te puedo ofrecer...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<FORM>
    <SELECT id="departamento" name="departamento"> 
        <OPTION value=0 selected>Elija departamento</OPTION>
        <OPTION value=1>BOACO</OPTION>
        <OPTION value=2>CARAZO</OPTION>
        <OPTION value=3>CHINANDEGA</OPTION>
</SELECT> 
<br />

<select id="municipio" disabled>
    <OPTION value=0 selected>Elija municipio</OPTION> 
</select> 

<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#departamento").change(function () {
            $("#municipio").prop('disabled', false);
            if (this.value == 1) {
                $("#municipio").html("<OPTION value=9>boaco</OPTION><OPTION value=59>teustepe</OPTION>");
            }
            else if (this.value == 2) {
                $("#municipio").html("<OPTION value=01>jinotepe</OPTION><OPTION value=41>diriamba</OPTION>");
            }
            else if (this.value == 3) {
                $("#municipio").html("<OPTION value=69>chinandolfi</OPTION><OPTION value=19>corintio</OPTION>");
            }
            else {
                $("#municipio").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#municipio").html("<OPTION value=0 selected>Elija municipio</OPTION>");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```